# Simple poetry for beginners

Tags: poetry

Can somebody suggest any traditional (possibly simple!) poetry for beginners, something that could be easily learnt by heart, just to help memorization of pronunciation and practicing?

Note that I'm not looking for learning resources that could be somehow "volatile", but for well-known classics in literature.

Maybe there are suitable poets studied by children at primary school...

Thanks!

Comment: one proverb：闰七不闰八，闰八过刀杀  (famous saying, can be looked up on the web) occurring in 《饥饿的女儿》 虹影著 (Daughter of the River), concerning it H. Goldblatt's translation says:"a bunch of kids were outdoors reciting some silly proverbs on 8 August 1967“

Comment: Help!!! I cannot find a (proper) translation!
I tried to look for each word on on-line dictionaries and I got something like "Leap 7 not leap 8, leap 8 passes over knife to kill". Can you give me some better explanation of it? Thanks!

Comment: reference is to leap months in the Chinese lunar calendar and resulting man-made calamities depending on which month is a leap month, for explanation google the proverb

Comment: why not google 儿童谚语? one result, http://doc.studyget.com/showdoc-35131.html has 15 rhyming proverbs

Comment: @user6065: Not exactly what I'm looking for, but good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.3kid.net/ertong/tangshi-sanbaishou.htm
has many for you to choose from; here are some examples:

### 咏鹅

-骆宾王

鹅，鹅，鹅，
曲项向天歌。
白毛浮绿水，
红掌拨清波。

---

### 春晓

-孟浩然

春眠不觉晓，
处处闻啼鸟。
夜来风雨声，
花落知多少。

---

### 登鹳雀楼

-王之涣

白日依山尽，
黄河入海流。
欲穷千里目，
更上一层楼。

Comment: Same comment as for answer http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/14900/11269 : good answer!

find more about:
骆宾王 (Luò Bīnwáng) at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luo_Binwang
孟浩然 (Meng Haoran) at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meng_Haoran
王之涣 (Wang Zhihuan) at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_Zhihuan

Answer (score 1):

### 夜宿山寺

李白

危楼高百尺，
手可摘星辰。
不敢高声语，
恐惊天上人。

---

### 静夜思

李白

床前明月光，
疑是地上霜。
举头望明月，
低头思故乡。

Comment: That's a good example of what I was exactly looking for: little pieces of poetry by a well-known poet: 李白 Lǐ Bái. Thanks very much!

People (like me) interested in knowing more about the autor, can refer to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Bai

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one

《悯农》

唐.李绅

锄禾日当午，
chú hé rì dāng wǔ,

汗滴禾下土。
hàn dī hé xià tǔ.

谁知盘中餐，
sheí zhī pán zhōng cān,

粒粒皆辛苦。
lì lì jiē xīn kǔ.

Answer (score 0):

Here I answer my own question, summing up the best answers arrived so far, with a basic collection of classical poets. As asked, the goal is not to provide a complete list, but to supply a starting point for beginners.

[骆宾王 (Luò Bīnwáng)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luo_Binwang)

[孟浩然 (Meng Haoran)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meng_Haoran)

[王之涣 (Wang Zhihuan)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_Zhihuan)

[李白 (Lǐ Bái)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Bai)

[杜甫 (Dù Fǔ)](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_Fu)

[李紳 (Li Shen)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Shen)

Beyond the question itself, interested people can find some examples below (I decided to report them so that they can be used as hints for researches on the net). In particular, 李白's **静夜思** seems to be one of the most famous, known by all Chinese speakers since childhood and reported very often around the web.

---

**咏鹅**

骆宾王

鹅，鹅，鹅，

曲项向天歌。

白毛浮绿水，

红掌拨清波。

---

**春晓**

孟浩然

春眠不觉晓，

处处闻啼鸟。

夜来风雨声，

花落知多少。

---

**登鹳雀楼**

王之涣

白日依山尽，

黄河入海流。

欲穷千里目，

更上一层楼。

---

**夜宿山寺**

李白

危楼高百尺，

手可摘星辰。

不敢高声语，

恐惊天上人。

---

**静夜思**

李白

床前明月光，

疑是地上霜。

举头望明月，

低头思故乡。

> **Jìng yè sī**
>
> Chuáng qián míng yuè guāng，
>
> Yí shì dì shàng shuāng.
>
> Jŭ tóu wàng míng yuè,
>
> Dī tóu sī gù xiāng.
>
> > **[quiet] [night] [think]**
> >
> > [bed] [front] [bright] [moon] [light]
> >
> > [suspect] [is] [ground] [on] [frost]
> >
> > [raise] [head] [look] [bright] [moon]
> >
> > [lower] [head] [think of] [old] [home village]